# Securing NodeRED dashboard from unwanted access

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red, ibm-cloud-functions, ibm-cloud-tools

I'm trying to create some kind of user authentication to prevent unwanted access to my NodeRED's User Interface. I've searched online and found 2 solutions, that for some reason didn't worked out. Here they are:

1. Tried to add the httpNodeAuth{user:"user", pass:"password"} key to the bluemix-settings.js but after that my dashboard kept prompting me to type username and password, even after I typed the password defined at pass:"password" field.
2. Added the user defined Environtment Variables NODE_RED_USERNAME : username and NODE_RED_PASSWORD : password . But nothing has changed.

Those solutions were sugested here: [How could I prohibit anonymous access to my NodeRed UI Dashboard on IBM Cloud(Bluemix)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49079541/how-could-i-prohibit-anonymous-access-to-my-nodered-ui-dashboard-on-ibm-cloudbl)
Thanks for the help, guys!

Here is a little bit of the 'bluemix-settings.js'

```
 autoInstallModules: true,

// Move the admin UI
httpAdminRoot: '/red',

// Serve up the welcome page
httpStatic: path.join(__dirname,"public"),

//GUI password authentication (ALEX)
httpNodeAuth: {user:"admin",pass:"$2y$12$W2VkVHvBTwRyGCEV0oDw7OkajzG3mdV3vKRDkbXMgIjDHw0mcotLC"},
functionGlobalContext: { },

// Configure the logging output
logging: {
```

Comment: An Update...I've tried to hash the password here: https://bcrypt-generator.com/ ,  but I still getting the same prompt for username/password...

Comment: Please add some more details to your question. Are you running in the cloud? If so which one? What version of node-red are you using? By default, and for some time now, when you spin up a new instance of node-red in the cloud you are given an option of securing it. Leaving it unsecure requires you to consciously select the unsecure option.

Comment: The web bcrypt generator probably failed because it used the wrong number of rounds (it looks to default to 12 and Node-RED is expecting 8)

Comment: Oh, sorry! I forgot to mention... I'm using NodeRED hosted at IBM Cloud, that's why my settings file it's called 'bluemix-settings.js'.
I've tried to hash the password with 4,8 and 10 rounds and got the same output. It kept prompting me to type username/password even after the typed

Comment: Sorry, it's not the number of rounds, its the length of the salt to generate.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the Node-RED docs [here](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/securing-node-red#http-node-security), you need to add a section as follows to the `settings.js` (or in the case of Bluemix/IBM Cloud the `bluemix-settings.js` file.

```
...
httpNodeAuth: {user:"user",pass:"$2a$08$zZWtXTja0fB1pzD4sHCMyOCMYz2Z6dNbM6tl8sJogENOMcxWV9DN."},
...
```

The `pass` files is a bcrypt hash of the password. There are 2 ways listed in the [docs](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/securing-node-red#generating-the-password-hash) about how to generate the hash in the correct way.

1. if you have a local copy of Node-RED installed you can use the following command:

   ```
   node-red admin hash-pw
   ```
2. As long as you have a local NodeJS install you can use the following:

   ```
   node -e "console.log(require('bcryptjs').hashSync(process.argv[1], 8));" your-password-here
   ```

   You may need to install `bcryptjs` first with `npm install bcryptjs` first.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yes I've added the httpNodeAuth section but I think I'm missing something, because I kept getting the same prompt over and over again, asking me to type to username and password, like if I was typing it wrong.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63620499/edit) question to show the section you have edited into `bluemix-settings.js` so we can see it in context

Comment: Also have you used the methods I mentioned, not the website?

Comment: I've added a bit of the 'bluemix-settings.js', if it's not enough, I can add more or even upload the file. Regarding the methods that you've mentioned, since I'm running NodeRED on IBM, is there a way for me to run those commands? Or maybe change the length of the salt on bcrypt-generator.com ? Thanks !

Comment: The second option is one you can run locally on your own machine

Comment: So are you sugesting install NodeJS on my local machine and then run the command 'node -e "console.log(require('bcryptjs').hashSync(process.argv[1], 8));" your-password-here' to hash the password. After that I just need to copy the hashed password string and paste it on my 'bluemix-settings.js' ?